Experimenting with the definition of a continuous map
Consider a map linking
topological spaces $(S,\,{\cal T})$ and  $(S^{\,\prime},\,{\cal
   T}^{\,\prime})~$:
$$ f:~S\longrightarrow S^{\,\prime}~. $$
The opens of $\cal T$ will be denoted with $U$, those of ${\cal T}^{\,\prime}$ with $U^{\,\prime}$.
Standard is this definition:
DEF 1
The map $f$ is continuous if the preimage of any open set is open:
$$ U'\in {\cal
   T}^{\,\prime} \Longrightarrow f^{-1}(U^{\,\prime}) \in {\cal T}~.  $$
$$
$$
Now try an alternative option:
DEF 2
For any pair of points $a\in S$ and $b\in S^{\,\prime}$ linked by $f$,
$$
f: ~ a\mapsto b~,
$$
and an arbitrary (not necessarily open) neighbourhood $N_b$ of $b$, there is a open neighbourhood $U_a$ of $a$, whose image belongs to $N_b$:
$$
\mbox{for}~ \forall ~N_b\ni b~~~\exists~ U_a~:~~f(U_a)\subseteq N_b~.
$$
It is easy to show that DEF 1 entails DEF 2. By definition of neighbourhood, any neighbourhood $N_b$ contains an open $U_b^{\,\prime}\ni b$. Its preimage $U_a\equiv f^{-1}(U_b^{\,\prime})$ contains the point $a$. By the definition DEF 1 of continuity, this $U_a$ is open. Thus we have proven that for any $N_b\ni b$ there is an open $U_a$ such that $f(U_a)\subseteq N_b$.   QED
I am now trying to check if the reverse is correct, i.e., if DEF 2 implies DEF 1. Suppose that $N_b$ is open. If $(S^{\,\prime},\,{\cal T}^{\,\prime})~$ is second-countable, DEF 2 ensures that for each basic open $U^{\,\prime}\in {\cal T}^{\,\prime}$ there is an open $U\in \cal T$ whose image is inside $U^{\,\prime}$. Moreover, the image coincides with $U^{\,\prime}$, lest $U^{\,\prime}$ is not basic. /PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I AM WRONG./ What remains is to point out that the union of all preimages is open. Hence open is the preimage of any open $N_b$.
Can the latter proof be extended to the general case, when $(S^{\,\prime},\,{\cal T}^{\,\prime})~$ is not second-countable?

You don't seem to be using your hypothesis of second countability.

"Basic" (used twice) seems meaningless here.

Your "DEF 2 ensures that for each basic open $U^{,\prime}\in {\cal T}^{,\prime}$ there is an open $U\in \cal T$ whose image is inside $U^{,\prime}$" makes no sense, as you can always choose $U=\varnothing$.

@AnneBauval. This needs no proof, because this is the definition, DEF 2. The question is whether DEF 2 is equivalent to DEF 1.  The proof of DEF 1 $\Longrightarrow$ DEF 2 is easy. The reverse statement is a challenge (to me).

@OrangeMushroom Thanks for your comment. I didn't know that this property is called "continuity at a point".

@AnneBauval The second countability implies that any open set can be written as a union of some basic elements. So, in my attempt, I "expanded" $N_b$ into basic sets $U^{,\prime}$, and stated that for each basic open $U^{,\prime}\in {\cal T}^{,\prime}$ there is an open $U\in\cal T$ whose image is not simlply inside $U^{,\prime}$, but coincides with $U^{,\prime}$, because $U^{,\prime}$ is basic. Was my statement wrong?

Second countability is irrelevant. If you have some basis $\mathcal B$ of the topology $\mathcal T'$ whatever its cardinality, every open set $U'\in\mathcal T'$ is a union of "basic" open sets. The trivial example $\mathcal B=\mathcal T'$ puts in evidence that your argument is flawed. Even if $f(U)\in\mathcal T'$ (which is not guaranteed at all) and if $U\ne\varnothing$, $$f(U)\subseteq U'\not\Rightarrow f(U)=U'.$$Moreover, even if $f(U)=U'$, you only have $U\subseteq f^{-1}(U')$, not $=$.

Let $U'\in\cal T'$. To prove that $U:=f^{-1}(U')$ is open, just check that it is a neighborhood of each of its points.

 So, let $a\in U$. Then, $b:=f(a)\in U'$ hence $U'$ is a neighborhood of $b$, so that (by def2) there is a neighborhood $U_a$ of $a$ s.t. $f(U_a)\subseteq U'$, i.e. $U_a\subseteq U$. Therefore, $U$ itself is a neighborhood of $a$, q.e.d.


Thank you, Anne. You have demonstrated that if $a\in U$ then $a\in U_a\subseteq U$, where $U_a$ is open. This is so for $\forall a \in U$. So any $a\in U$ is an interior point, and therefore $U$ coincides with its interior $U^o$. One last question: how to prove from $U=U^o$ that $U$ is open? I guess, this is so because the interior $U^o$ is the union of all opens contained in $U$, is that right?

@Michael_1812 The interior of any set is open.

@K.Jiang Yes, the interior $U^o$ is open, because it is a union of all opens contained in $U$.

I agree with both of you. One nitpicking though, Michael: I did not need $U_a$ to be open. Only to be a neighborhood of $a$.

@AnneBauval (1) You are saying that if $b:=f(a)\in U'$ then $U'$ is a neighbourhood of $b$. This is warranted only if $U'$ is open. (Please correct me if I am wrong.) Should we not set $U'$ open a priori? (2) By setting $U'$ open, and then by proving that $U$ is open, we show that the map is continuous, correct?

Indeed, whence my "Let $U'\in\cal T'$. To prove that $U:=f^{-1}(U')$ is open...".
